# How to change a single value inside of an object inside of an array in a mongoose model and save it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a website where you can sign in, and create tasks, and then check them out. I am working with mongoose, and the tasks are saved inside an array of type Task in a User model. Each task has a "done" value which is either "true" or "false"(not a boolean), when the user checks a task as done an ajax Put request is sent to the server and needs to change the "done" value. I cant change the done value. I think the problem is accessing the "done" in the "task" object in the Task array in the User model.

I've tried all sort of syntaxes shown in the mongoose official website, but nothing is seems to work.

```
//send a task(a string with the actual task) and the new done situation to the server
    function putDone(task,done){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Put',
            data:{
                task,
                done,
            },
            url: '/tasks/tasks',
        })
    }
```

```
//find the task from all the user's tasks and replaces the done situation
router.put("/tasks",(req,res) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < req.user.tasks.length; i++){
        if(req.user.tasks[i].task == req.body.task){
            User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {'username': req.user.username},
                {'$set': { 'req.user.tasks[i-1].done': req.body.done }},
                {'new': true},
                function(err,updatedUser){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        console.log(req.body.task + ", " + req.body.done);
                        console.log(updatedUser.tasks[i-1]);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

the models as asked in the answers:

```
//task schema
//var Task = mongoose.Schema.Types.Task;
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 8,
        maxLength: 20,
    },
    archive:{
        type: Array,
        required: false,
    },
    tasks:{
        type: Array,
        required: false,
    }
});

let User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```
//task schema

let taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    task:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
    },
    done:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: true,
    }
});

let Task = module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);//find by first param the collection, can add third param of actual collection name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following helps you. Please note I did not have the chance of running the code. Also, I hope you are fine with async/await. If this code does not run please let me know why!

```
router.put('/tasks', async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.user
  const { task, done } = req.body

  try {
    const userFromDB = await User.findOne({ username }).exec()

    if (!userFromDB) {
      throw new Error('User not found')
    }

    const taskFromDB = userFromDB.tasks.find(taskFromDBInList => taskFromDBInList.task === task)

    if (!taskFromDB) {
      throw new Error('Task not found')
    }

    taskFromDB.done = done

    await userFromDB.save()

    console.log(`${task}, ${done}`)
    console.log(taskFromDB)
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

UPDATE:

For the schemas to work you need to define the User's `tasks` as an `Array` of the `taskSchema`. If the code below does not work try this: `tasks: [taskSchema]`

```
// Schemas

const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  task: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
  },
  done: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true,
  }
});

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 8,
    maxLength: 20,
  },
  archive: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
  },
  tasks: {
    type: [taskSchema],
    required: false,
  }
});

// Models

const Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @VI4dimyr, it didn't seem to work, i dont really understand the code so I cant tell what exactly went wrong, but it looks like the object have been changed but didnt saved in the database

Comment: Do you have a separate model/schema for the task, could you provide the structure? Would you understand a solution with then/catch instead of async/await better?

Comment: ill edit the question with the models, as for the then/catch i understand the principal but Ive never worked with it before

Comment: Ok for then/catch async/await I suggest watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE and for the code please try adding `await taskFromDB.save()` before `await userFromDB.save()` maybe you don't even need the `await userFromDB.save()` after this

Comment: Oh the type of your tasks inside the User schema should not be `Array` but `[taskSchema]` so you need to define the Task before User, because at the moment your User tasks are just an Array and Task itself is not connected to the user

Comment: thanks this might be the problem, do you know of a way to convert my data base into a new model data base with all the current data?

Comment: You can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongoose so you can write a migration to change your data structure, or if you just need it once, write a function to find all tasks for a user and store the tasks into that users tasks, then run this for all users

Comment: hey vladimyr, im trying to change the User tasks to [Task.schema] but i keep getting errors, what is the syntax i should write it in? currently im using ```type: [task.schema]```

Comment: Please check the answer I updated it! And checkout https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html